# Is it possible to use GROUP BY with GROUP_CONCAT on same column with limit condition

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

```
SELECT id,businessName,GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM tbl_business LIMIT 0,1
```

Above query is giving me below results

```
1   Camp San Fransisco  1,4
```

Now if i apply GROUP BY and  limit on same query, GROUP_CONCAT column is not giving me same results as before.

```
SELECT id,businessName,GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM tbl_business GROUP BY id LIMIT 0,1
```

Query Results

```
1   Camp San Fransisco  1
```

I'm using GROUP BY id for fetching a unique records with some where condition.

Is there are any alternatives for using GROUP_BY with GROUP_CONCAT or any other methods for MySQL which can be usefull here.

I want to preserve first query results with id so i just have to call second query based on first results id if it is possible. I can not remove GROUP BY id because of multiple table's LEFT JOIN and some SUB QUERY are depends on it

Above queries are just for explanation purpose , original query is much longer.

Actual Query :

```
SELECT bs.id,bs.businessName,bs.businessDesc,bs.latitude,bs.longitude,bs.slug,bs.contactNo,bs.location,bs.isAddedBy,bs.createdDate,cat.categoryName as category,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(bcat.categoryName) SEPARATOR ', ') as subcategory,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_reviews WHERE referenceId = bs.id) as totalReview,
        (SELECT CEIL(AVG(rating)) FROM tbl_reviews WHERE referenceId = bs.id) as avgRating,
        (SELECT imageName FROM tbl_business_images as bimg WHERE bimg.businessId = bs.id LIMIT 1) as bImage,

        (
            (ACOS
                (
                    SIN(37.09024 * PI() / 180) * SIN(bs.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(37.09024 * PI() / 180) * COS(bs.latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(
                                (-95.712891 - bs.longitude) * PI() / 180)
                )* 180 / PI()
            ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
        ) as distance,

        (SELECT 
                (DATEDIFF(bs.createdDate,NOW()) * 5) + 
                ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_business_images WHERE businessId = bs.id) * 2) + 
                ((SELECT count(id) FROM tbl_business_views WHERE businessId = bs.id) * 2) + 
                ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_reviews WHERE referenceId = bs.id) * 10)) 
        as totalPoint
        FROM tbl_business as bs
        LEFT JOIN tbl_category as cat
        ON bs.businessCat = cat.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_business_subcategories as bsubs
        ON bs.id = bsubs.businessId
        LEFT JOIN tbl_category as bcat
        ON bsubs.subcategoryId = bcat.id
        WHERE bs.isActive = 'y' 
        GROUP BY bs.slug
```

Current Query Output :

```
id  businessName  businessDesc  latitude  longitude slug  contactNo location  isAddedBy createdDate category  subcategory totalReview avgRating bImage  distance  totalPoint  

1   test  test   45.14  -122.82   test   1234567890  USA  c   2018-09-29 11:38:58   Category   Subcategory1,subcategory2   1   5   image.png  2382.763331498852   -4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your first query does not do `group by id`

Comment: that is what i'm telling, if i use GROUP BY i'm not getting correct result with limit. please see my second query.

Comment: Please update your question with sample data. I feel there is a logic issue.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Your extended query is find; but need to look at some sample data (we dont need your actual data; just some minimal data with relevant columns); expected output would work.